# fill Snipper error

Tags: android, eclipse

i have the following codes in my project:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.login_username_spinner);

ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, _users);
spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

it works good and fill my Spinner.but when i click on my spinner a NullPointerException will occur!

at this step i want no OnItemSelectedListener.
can anyone help me please?!

my database has 4 same records.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1.check the class that u get data from
2.check the database may have empty columns
3.check if _id column defined, if u are using cursorAdapter
4.check manifest file for defining all activities correctly
5. if none of above solutions work then try writing log.d("TAG","methode name") in everywhere to recognize where is the problem